# Custom associations between Hibernate Entities

Tags: java, hibernate, associations

I have two Entity classes which are both written into a separate table. In my database there is no connection between the two tables via key, but I want to implement a logical association between the entities.

```
@Entity
public class One{

  @ID
  long id;

  String name;

  List<Two> aListOfTwos;;

  public List<Two> getAListOfTwos(){
    //return some Twos based on some custom query, p.e. "All Twos created last week"
  }



}



@Entity
public class Two{

  @ID
  long id;

  Date createdAt;

  String name;

}
```

Of course I could just write an appropriate query in the getAListOfTwos method, but the I would need to have access to the Session Object which I don't want. Is there an other way to specify such an association in Hibernate?

Many Thanks
Paul

Answer (score 0):

You can go for one to many mapping using join table. And if your association is manytomany, it anyway needs a third table.

Comment: Thanks, but this is what I actually try to avoid. And how would this additional table make sure that I get only the "Twos created last week"